# content inside of container but background and border outside of container

Tags: html, css

How would I make the border run full width of the view port rather then been stuck inside the container. There are 2 different colors.

the issue is I cant get both border colors inline for the entire view port only inside the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8039/

css

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

header .col-sm-8, header .col-sm-4, header .col-sm-6 {
    padding: 0;
}
.container-full {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #c9dee3 50%, #f4f9f5 50%);
}

.green {
    background: #f4f9f5;
    border-top: 7px solid #a9cab3;
    border-left: 7px solid #a9cab3;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.blue {
    background: #c9dee3;
    border-top: 7px solid #70c9d9;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
}

.blue .col-sm-6 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="container-full">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="blue">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            something will go in here
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            something will go in here
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="green">
                        something will go in here
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't getting your actual problem. What is your desired output.

Comment: The border to stretch the entire viewport, but I want to keep the content wrapped inside a container like so with the backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Remove div with class `container`

```
<header>
<div class="container-full">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="blue">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        something will go in here
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        something will go in here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="green">
                    something will go in here
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That creates a problem where the content is not wrapped inside a container then.